# How to secure Spring Server using Facebook Login from Mobile App

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, facebook-login, restful-authentication

I am working on a mobile app that has a back end server providing a RESTful API but need to get security setup. We will be using only Facebook login from the front end side my question is how do I go about securing the RESTful API this way?

I have read a lot about how Spring Security works and the different authentication methods but all of them seem to deal with a username/password combination. Is there a way I can provide the mobile app an access token based on successful authentication through facebook from the front end?

Comment: You're probably looking for OAuth.

Comment: @chrylis thank you, I will take a look and see if I can figure it out. I found a simple tutorial on it here: http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/10/spring-security-oauth2-integration.html

Comment: Keep in mind that Boot has recently added some additional support for OAuth embeds; I haven't used them, but I know they're there.

Comment: @chrylis thanks for the tip, I am super new to Spring right now anyway so I am just trying to find one solution that will work for the time being.

Comment: If you're new to Spring, you definitely should be using Boot; it eliminates all the boilerplate configuration and lets you focus on getting your application built.

Comment: @chrylis I believe I am already using Spring Boot actually! As I already have a simple RESTful web server built that is serving content from a database. I followed one of the guides on Spring's website.

Comment: https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/ Better late than never) And it is funny to get answer after 2 years)))